# Repeating "in" statement in T-SQL - can it be put centrally somewhere?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a large number of stored procs that all execute similar bits of selection logic:

```
WHERE
 @CustGroup = 'X' AND CUST_TYPE in ('X1', 'X2', 'B1', 'C1')
OR
 @CustGroup = 'Y' AND CUST_TYPE in ('Y1', 'A1', 'B2', 'C2')
OR
 @CustGroup = 'Z' AND CUST_TYPE in ('X2', 'Y2', 'D1', 'D2')
OR
 @CustGroup = 'MAIN' AND CUST_TYPE in ('Y1', 'A1', 'B2', 'C2', 'X2', 'Y2', 'D1', 'D2')
```

Is it possible to:

A)

Put these "in" selections into a variable of somekind?

```
@XGroup = 'X1', 'X2', 'B1', 'C1'
WHERE
 @CustGroup = 'X' AND CUST_TYPE in (@XGroup)
```

and if so B)

Put these "in" selections centrally somewhere so they can be re-used with different sprocs?

Comment: Why not put those in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to B,

Create a table

```
create table CUST_TYPE_LOOKUP (
  key varchar(10) not null,   -- or whatever type
  value varchar(10) not null  -- or whatever type
);

create index foo on CUST_TYPE_LOOKUP (key);
```

Fill it with data.

```
Key1  X1
Key1  X2
Key1  B1
Key1  C1
Key2  Y1
Key2  A1
Key2  B2
Key2  C2
```

Then use:

```
WHERE
  @CustGroup = 'X' AND CUST_TYPE in (select value from CUST_TYPE_LOOKUP where key = 'Key1')
 OR
  @CustGroup = 'Y' AND CUST_TYPE in (select value from CUST_TYPE_LOOKUP where key = 'Key2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your main queries with a temp table, or table variable, like this:

```
DECLARE @cgt TABLE(CustGroup VARCHAR(5), CustType VARCHAR(5));

INSERT  @cgt VALUES('X','X1'), ('X','X2'), ('X','B1'), ('X','C1');
INSERT  @cgt VALUES('Y','Y1'), ('Y','A1'), ('Y','B2'), ('Y','C2');
INSERT  @cgt VALUES('Z','X2'), ('Z','Y2'), ('Z','D1'), ('Z','D2');
INSERT  @cgt VALUES('MAIN','Y1'), ('MAIN','A1'), ('MAIN','B2'), ('MAIN','C2')
, ('MAIN','X2'), ('MAIN','Y2'), ('MAIN','D1'), ('MAIN','D2');

SELECT  t.* 
FROM    MyTable t
JOIN    @cgt cgt    ON  cgt.CustGroup = @CustGroup
                    AND cgt.CustType = t.CUST_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of array you're describing isn't really possible in TSQL, but there are some things you can do. You can use dynamic SQL and create the selection criteria once, reusing that bit to create the remaining queries. Dynamic SQL has performance and security issues (if you allow external users to alter the query strings). I think the simplest method would be to create a view or set of views based on your common selection criteria, then INNER JOIN your later queries against those views. That allows you to quickly change the logic in the view - in one location - and have it affect any other queries based on it. For example, if the selection criteria you have above applies to all "top 10" clients:

```
CREATE VIEW vTopTenCustomers
AS
SELECT CustomerID
FROM Customers
WHERE
 CustGroup = 'X' AND CUST_TYPE in ('X1', 'X2', 'B1', 'C1')
OR
 CustGroup = 'Y' AND CUST_TYPE in ('Y1', 'A1', 'B2', 'C2')
OR
 CustGroup = 'Z' AND CUST_TYPE in ('X2', 'Y2', 'D1', 'D2')
OR
 CustGroup = 'MAIN' AND CUST_TYPE in ('Y1', 'A1', 'B2', 'C2', 'X2', 'Y2', 'D1', 'D2')
```

Then when you need to run a query against just the top 10, join to that view:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN vTopTenCustomers
    ON Customers.CustomerID = vTopTenCustomers.CustomerID
```

You'll need to be careful with your indexes - you'll probably want nonclustered indexes on CustGroup and Cust_Type to avoid poor performance on the view.